# Help Identifying a minifigure head - white, like a mime or clown

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

I have looked everywhere I know to look but can't find this minifigure head listed.  Any help appreciated.

[image: minifig head, white, like a mime or clown]

Comment: looks really similar to the sad clown head https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0915#T=C&C=1
the cross near the eyes are indicative of a clown-like figure, maybe a mime.

Comment: Could you confirm that it's a LEGO minifig ?

Comment: It is definitely a lego minifigure I got it out of the build a minifigure bin at the Lego store.  I have searched clowns, and mimes and looked through the entire minifigure database on bricklink and can't find a match.

Comment: I have looked through all the white heads on BrickLink, and find no match. Since OP said that they found it at the Build-A-Minifig bin, my guess is that it may be a head from an upcoming minifig/promotional item that wasn't released yet. An interesting find for sure!

Comment: I think it’s a Lego clown face from a mystery pack. I don’t know what series

Answer (score 16):

I talked to a Lego expert on the lego.com online chat.  He told me that this particular lego head was an exclusive part for the Build a Minifigure bin and gave me the part number for it 6257472 mini figure head #2829.  I didn't know there were exclusive parts in the minifigure bin, I wonder if this is something new.  He seemed quite surprised when he found it in the lego database as being exclusive to the build a minifigure bin.

Comment: Great find, and thanks for coming back and letting us know :)

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I have a chimpanzee 95327pb02 that is difficult to find because it was in the Build a Fig bin, whereas the alternate print of it (95327pb01) is easy to find because it's included in 2 sets.

Comment: @raystafarian good to know!  Not knowing the build a fig bin had exclusives for a minute I thought they were kidding!

Comment: @bricknerdz I stopped by build a fig Tokyo today to try to find that head, no luck but they had other mimes I haven't seen

Comment: @Raystafarian  oooo cool, did you take pics?

Comment: I did not think to, no. Sorry

Comment: @raystafarian no worries, it just now has me wondering what exclusives the mini figure bin may have

Comment: Nuts. I found this thread while searching for a way to identify miscellaneous heads and read the discussion about build-a-fig stations. That got me interested in finding a LEGO store. googled the closest one and sifted thru a few photos. Lo and behold: a shot of this mime from last year. [SF LEGO Store - Mime Minifig Head](https://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/cPYX3zQzCAIUVIQ6W3VVYQ?select=cLvVqG5kkoxvcCbwEw0vfg&utm_source=ishare&utm_content=photo)

Answer (score 6):

Found it on brick link [Catalog: Parts: Minifigure, Head: 3626cpb2325](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb2325&name=Minifigure,%20Head%20Mime%20Smiling%20Face,%20Black%20Star%20Eyes%20with%20White%20Pupils%20Pattern%20-%20Hollow%20Stud&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Head%5D#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22iconly%22:0%7D).

Title says it's a Minifigure, Head Mime Smiling Face, Black Star Eyes with White Pupils Pattern - Hollow Stud

[image: Minifigure, Head Mime Smiling Face]